# Does anyone know how to use m2mqtt on Unity3D (with Tls1.2)?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, ssl, mqtt

I am developing an AR app in Unity and I need to connect to an MQTT broker with TLS protocol enabled.

I am able to connect to non-TLS enabled MQTT brokers successfully(In unity), and I can use the certificate the admin gave me with the MQTT explorer application to connect to the TLS enabled broker successfully. (**the broker is using TLS 1.2**)

But when I attempt to connect to the TLS enabled server with the **paho-m2mqtt** library for c# in Unity (https://github.com/eclipse/paho.mqtt.m2mqtt), I get the following exception:

```
Connection error: uPLibrary.Networking.M2Mqtt.Exceptions.MqttConnectionException: Exception connecting to the broker
---> System.ArgumentException: SSL/TLS protocol version not supported
```

This is the code I am using to test the connection (*I have the server certificate, client certificate, and client key stored at Assets/StreamingAssests, and I could be using the certs wrong when making the MqttClient, but this is how most people were connecting*):

```
public void connect(broker, port)
{
    string caCertLoc = Application.streamingAssetsPath + "/ca.crt";
    string clientCertLoc = Application.streamingAssetsPath + "/clientCert.crt";

    X509Certificate2 caCert = new X509Certificate2(caCertLoc);

    X509Certificate2 clientCert = new X509Certificate2(clientCertLoc);

    MqttClient client = new MqttClient(broker, port, true, 
                                       X509Certificate.CreateFromCertFile(caCertLoc), 
                                       X509Certificate2.CreateFromCertFile(clientCertLoc), 
                                       MqttSslProtocols.TLSv1_2, 
                                       MyRemoteCertificateValidationCallback);
    
    string clientId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

    try
    {
        client.Connect(clientId);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        UnityEngine.Debug.LogError("Connection error: " + e);
    }
}
```

I would appreciate any help as I am completely stuck on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, turn out I was using an older .dll for M2Mqtt - THe implementation above works now (only change is the clinetCert has to be a .pfx)